# Error instalación Git en Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, git

Me está trayendo por el camino de la amargura...Al intentar instalar Git me salta el siguiente error que no sé cómo solucionar. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida. Gracias!

```js
marlena@marlena-K55VD:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  git-man liberror-perl
Paquetes sugeridos:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
  gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 actualizados, 3 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 4 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 22,8 kB/4.733 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 33,9 MB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] S
Ign:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17025-1
Err:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17025-1
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.139.75 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17025-1_all.deb  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.139.75 80]
E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?
```

Comment: ¿Ya ejecutaste `apt-get update` o `sudo apt-get install git --fix-missing` como recomienda el instalador?

Comment: me está pasando exactamente lo mismo al intentar instalar otro paquete

Comment: @JonathanOrta Sí, ha sido lo primero que ejecuté al saltar el error pero no me soluciona nada...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mí me pasó lo mismo; lo resolví cambiando los repositorios en **/etc/apt/sources.list**

En mi caso, sustituí todos los repositorios que empezaban por es. y utilicé los de Estados Unidos, por ejemplo, cambié:

```
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

por

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

Comment: SOLUCIONADO. ¡¡¡Mil gracias!!! ¡Espero que te regalen un buen jamón por Navidad!

Comment: A mí tamibén me ha ayudado, Muchas gracias por la respuesta Tvs y por la pregunta Shurlena. Estária genial que marcaras la respuesta de  @tvs como respuesta valida, y por que no, darle un voto positivo también a su respuesta. Es también una forma de dar las gracias, y además ayudaras a que tú pregunta y la respuesta se posicionen mejor , y la pueda ver más gente que les sirva de ayuda como a nosotros :). Muchas gracias

Comment: @RubialesAlberto gracias por la puntualización, así he hecho. Lo tendré presente para futuras preguntas :)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré en un foro en inglés la misma solución pero sin tocar el fichero: se accede a la aplicación **Software y actualizaciones** solapa **Software de Ubuntu** y en el desplegable **Descargar desde:** seleccionar **Servidor principal**.

Cuando pasen unos días deshacer el cambio para volver a descargar desde el país de origen.

Saludos!

Comment: Sería bueno colocar el enlace ala fuente de dónde obtuviste la respuesta

Comment: Luis Moreno a mi también me funcionó así.